# How do the if-else statements in this function from a tutorial make any sense?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm going through [this tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-full-featured-music-player-with-vuetify--cms-31228) for a simple playlist with Vue.

I'm confused by the author's `play()` function, particularly the series of if-else statements. It appears to check whether `index` is a number, and if it is (and I can't imagine how it wouldn't be), it seems to skip the rest of the code that checks for whether the selected track is the same as the current track, among other things [(link to the repo and function in question here)](https://github.com/tutsplus/build-a-music-player-with-vuejs-and-vuetify/blob/a7c1fa403011cd7202a1747514248476aa181e09/src/Player.vue#L121):

```
play (index) {
  let selectedTrackIndex = this.playlist.findIndex(track => track === this.selectedTrack)

  if (typeof index === 'number') {
    index = index

  } else if (this.selectedTrack) {
    if (this.selectedTrack != this.currentTrack) {
      this.stop()
    }
    index = selectedTrackIndex
  } else {
    index = this.index
  }

  let track = this.playlist[index].howl

  if (track.playing()) {
    return
  } else {
    track.play()
  }

  this.selectedTrack = this.playlist[index]
  this.playing = true
  this.index = index
}
```

The author's summary of the above code:

> The method takes an index as the parameter, which specifies the track
>   to be played. First, we get the index of the selected track. Then, we
>   make some checks to determine the value of the index. If an index is
>   provided as an argument and it's a number, then we use it. If a track
>   is selected, we use the index of the selected track. If the selected
>   track is different from the current one, we use the stop() method to
>   stop the current one. Finally, if neither an index argument is passed
>   nor a track is selected, we use the value of the index data property.

I checked MDN and a few other sources and didn't see anything special about an `if()` followed by an `else if()` in JavaScript. So I figure I have to be missing something here. Why is a validation check on `index` tied to checking whether the selected track is the same as the current track? The other checks inside the `else if()` and `else` blocks seem like stuff you wouldn't want to leave out, and yet his live demo of the app works. I asked the author to elaborate in the comments of the article but the article is almost a year old, so I'm not sure if he'll get back to me. Thanks to everyone in advance.

Comment: So `play()` vs `play(2)`

Answer (score 2):

It's not really a validation test, it's just detecting whether an argument was supplied or not. If the argument isn't supplied, or it's not a number, the function performs default behaviors.

If the caller uses `track.play(2)`, they're specifically telling it to play track 2. The test `if (typeof index == 'number')` will succeed, and we'll use that given index.

If the caller uses `track.play()`, `index` will be `undefined`, which isn't a number, so that test will fail, and then we'll continue with the `else if` test. If there's a selected track, we use that (first stopping the current track if it's different).

If there's no selected track, we fall through to the final `else` clause, which uses the `index` property of the current object.

Comment: Thank you! Knew I was missing something. So I followed the steps starting with the user clicking on a track, and when the user hits the play button, I remembered that the event handler has parentheses (line 21 of `PlayerControlsBars.vue`), unlike the stopTrack and pauseTrack handlers which are just references to the functions. Why the parentheses for `playTrack()` but none for the other two? Are they there to allow for an index to be passed if one is available? I don't get that either though, since an index isn't determined until the event is emitted up to the parent.

Comment: Because when you're stopping or pausing, the only track that matters is the one that's already playing. But when you want to play a track, you have choices.

Comment: Right. The thing I don't get though is that in the `PlayerControlsBars` component, there is no index prop, no reference to the index, etc. in the entire component, so it seems that when `playTrack(index)` is called and emits the `playtrack` event up to the parent, an index would never be present. So I don't even see the point of including it there.

Comment: The last line of `play()` is `this.index = index`. So once you play a track, that becomes the default index the next time `track.play()` is called.

Comment: Okay, so what is the purpose of passing an `index` as a payload up to the parent component of `PlayerControlsBars` when no index is even referred to in that component?

Comment: It doesn't pass it to the parent. It uses it to get the track with `this.selectedTrack = this.playlist[index]`.